# how to add code snippets plugin in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have created an online build of CKEditor 4.20.1 with the plugin [CodeSnippet](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/codesnippet). The editor is working fine. But if I set the toolbar on my PHP page, then the code Snippet button is not showing in the toolbar of CKeditor, while all other toolbar buttons are working fine with this. I have searched on google but did not find any answer.

```
<textarea name="text_editor" id="text_editor" ></textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'text_editor', {                  
toolbar:[['Source','Table','codesnippet']],
height:['350px']
});
</script>
```

With the above code, the "source" and "Table" buttons (icons) are visible and working fine. But codesnippet button is not visible.
But if I do not define toolbar on the page (code shown below), then the CodeSnippet button is visible and working fine. **But I need only a few tools for a particular web page and some other tools for some other pages.**

```
<textarea name="text_editor" id="text_editor" ></textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'text_editor', {                  
height:['350px']
});
</script>
```

Below I attached the build-config.js of CKeditor, where you can see the codesnippet plugin added automatically by CKEditor online builder.

```
/\*\*

* @license Copyright (c) 2003-2022, CKSource Holding sp. z o.o. All rights reserved.
* For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license/
  \*/

/\*\*

* This file was added automatically by CKEditor builder.
* You may re-use it at any time to build CKEditor again.
* 
* If you would like to build CKEditor online again
* (for example, to upgrade), visit one of the following links:
* 
* (1) https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder
*     Visit online builder to build CKEditor from scratch.
* 
* (2) https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder/14bc102b680c88ab211db5638741532b
*     Visit online builder to build CKEditor, starting with the same setup as before.
* 
* (3) https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder/download/14bc102b680c88ab211db5638741532b
*     Straight download link to the latest version of CKEditor (Optimized) with the same setup as before.
* 
* NOTE:
* This file is not used by CKEditor, you may remove it.
* Changing this file will not change your CKEditor configuration.
  \*/

var CKBUILDER_CONFIG = {
skin: 'moono-dark',
preset: 'full',
ignore: \[
'.DS_Store',
'.bender',
'.editorconfig',
'.gitattributes',
'.gitignore',
'.idea',
'.jscsrc',
'.jshintignore',
'.jshintrc',
'.mailmap',
'.npm',
'.nvmrc',
'.travis.yml',
'bender-err.log',
'bender-out.log',
'bender.ci.js',
'bender.js',
'dev',
'gruntfile.js',
'less',
'node_modules',
'package-lock.json',
'package.json',
'tests'
\],
plugins : {
'basicstyles' : 1,
'bidi' : 1,
'blockquote' : 1,
'clipboard' : 1,
'codesnippet' : 1,
'colorbutton' : 1,
'colordialog' : 1,
'contextmenu' : 1,
'copyformatting' : 1,
'dialogadvtab' : 1,
'div' : 1,
'elementspath' : 1,
'enterkey' : 1,
'filebrowser' : 1,
'find' : 1,
'floatingspace' : 1,
'font' : 1,
'format' : 1,
'forms' : 1,
'horizontalrule' : 1,
'htmlwriter' : 1,
'iframe' : 1,
'image' : 1,
'indentblock' : 1,
'indentlist' : 1,
'justify' : 1,
'language' : 1,
'link' : 1,
'list' : 1,
'liststyle' : 1,
'magicline' : 1,
'maximize' : 1,
'pastefromgdocs' : 1,
'pastefromword' : 1,
'pastetext' : 1,
'pastetools' : 1,
'preview' : 1,
'quicktable' : 1,
'removeformat' : 1,
'resize' : 1,
'scayt' : 1,
'selectall' : 1,
'showblocks' : 1,
'showborders' : 1,
'smiley' : 1,
'sourcearea' : 1,
'specialchar' : 1,
'stylescombo' : 1,
'tab' : 1,
'table' : 1,
'tableresize' : 1,
'tableselection' : 1,
'tabletools' : 1,
'templates' : 1,
'toolbar' : 1,
'undo' : 1,
'wysiwygarea' : 1
},
languages : {
'bn' : 1,
'en' : 1,
'hi' : 1
}
};
```

Initially, I thought there was a problem with the online build, so I did it a second time (online build), but the problem remained the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on actually digging in the source of the plugin, the toolbar command is case sensitive and needs to be `CodeSnippet`.

Based on init function in https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/master/plugins/codesnippet/plugin.js which defines

```
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.ui.addButton && editor.ui.addButton( 'CodeSnippet', {
            label: editor.lang.codesnippet.button,
            command: 'codeSnippet',
            toolbar: 'insert,10'
        } );
    },
```

The first argument to addButton defines what exactly is needed

Comment: Thank you for your help. CodeSnippet works perfectly. C and S in upper case.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the confirmation, I will update the answer for future people googling